# JPA Criteria API - LEFT OUTER JOIN not populating a @OneToMany List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

This is my entity:

```
public class Patrimony {

 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patrimony")
    @JsonManagedReference 
    private
    List<Patrpos> positions;
}
```

My code is:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Patrimony> cq = cb.createQuery(Patrimony.class);
Root<Patrimony> root = cq.from(Patrimony.class);

Join<Patrimony, UserProfile> userprofile = root.join(Patrimony_.userprofile);
Join<Patrimony, Patrpos> joinPatrpos = root.join(Patrimony_.positions, JoinType.LEFT);
root.fetch(Patrimony_.positions);

joinPatrpos.on(cb.equal(joinPatrpos.get(Patrpos_.dtPatrpos), dateproc.minusDays(1)));

cq.select(root);

TypedQuery<Patrimony> query = manager.createQuery(cq);

List<Patrimony> list = query.getResultList();
```

The query that is being generated looks ok, and it's something like:

```
select
    patrimony0_.id as id1_10_0_,
    positions3_.id as id1_11_1_,
    patrimony0_.category_id as categor15_10_0_,
    patrimony0_.description as descript2_10_0_,
    patrimony0_.vl_valuation_start as vl_valu14_10_0_,
    positions3_.dt_patrpos as dt_patrp2_11_1_,
    positions3_.vl_patrpos as vl_patrp6_11_1_,
from
    patrimony patrimony0_ 
inner join
    userprofile userprofil1_ 
        on patrimony0_.userprofile_id=userprofil1_.id 
left outer join
    patrpos positions2_ 
        on patrimony0_.id=positions2_.patrimony_id 
        and (
            positions2_.dt_patrpos=?
        ) 
inner join
    patrpos positions3_ 
        on patrimony0_.id=positions3_.patrimony_id 
where userprofil1_.id=161
```

The query seems to be returning all the data that I need, the entity Patrimony is being returned with all the data ok, except the "List positions" attribute, which is always null.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try fetch?

Comment: I guess I tried.   root.fetch(Patrimony_.positions);

Comment: Have you tried to set logging level of hibernate to trace?

Comment: Why don't you think the problem is with your predicate? `joinPatrpos.on(cb.equal(joinPatrpos.get(Patrpos_.dtPatrpos), dateproc.minusDays(1)));` Where do you define dateproc? Then your query doesn't include it but includes a bunch of other fields and finally you haven't included your `Patrpos` entity in the question. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Reviewing the unit test, I notice that I didn't call flush() and clear() after inserting the test data.  I added flush and clear before calling the query and all the entities were populated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing the unit test, I notice that I didn't call flush() and clear() after inserting the test data.  I added flush and clear before calling the query and all the entities were populated correctly.

Thank you all for the comments.